# "Дощовий день" чи "дощовитий день"

Tags: вибір-слова

Цікавить який прикметник ("дощовий" чи "дощовитий") потрібно використовувати зі словом "день"/"ніч"/"ранок. Професор Пономарів у своєму [блозі](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2015/12/151207_ponomariv_blog77_ko) пише:

> Часом збіднюють лексичний запас, не розрізняючи паронімів, зокрема
>   дощовий (російське дождевой) і дощовитий (російське дождливый). Дощова
>   вода, дощові краплини, дощовий потік, **але дощовитий день**, дощовите
>   літо, дощовита погода. У публічному мовленні на все кажуть дощовий.

Однак, якщо заглянути в СУМ, то бачимо:

> **[ДОЩОВИ́ТИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/doshhovytyj)**, а, е, **рідко**. Те саме, що дощовий

**[Дощовий](http://sum.in.ua/s/doshhovyj)**:

> 2. Багатий дощами. Марою насунулась **ніч дощова**, А завтра знов сонце загляне в віконце (Леся Українка, I, 1951, 157);

З чого я можу зробити висновок, що можна казати і "дощовий день" і "дощовитий день", а перший варіант навіть кращий, бо коло слова "дощовитий" стоїть позначка "рідко".

То як все ж таки буде правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/doshhovutuj-i-doshhovuj)

[image]

> **Дощовитий** – це «багатий на дощі»: дощовитий день, дощовита осінь, дощовита погода, дощовитий рік.
>
> **Дощовий** – відносний прикметник до слова «дощ»: дощова вода, дощові краплини, дощові хмари, дощовий черв’як.

[Оnlinecorrector.](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9/)

> Замініть прикметник *дощовий*, якщо мовиться про щось, багате дощами, на стилістично кращий варіант: *дощовитий.*

Отже, день ***дощовитий***